# DataTable select filtered row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to select the row that the filter showed. And if possible delete that row.
I am using the following code to filter the DataTable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class SearchWindow : Form
    {
        public frPlanMain refTofrPlanMain;

        public SearchWindow(frPlanMain f) //<<Edit made here 
        {
            refTofrPlanMain = f;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                (refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Vodic = '{0}'", searchTBoxW.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Where : refToPlanMain represents the referance to the form that contains the DataGridView; dGVPlan is the DataGridView and the data source is a .xls file that i use OLEDB to import it.

Comment: And what problem do you have with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you won't be able to delete the excel row if you are using OLEDB to query directly from an .xls file. You will have to use native interop and load an instance of excel inside your program and delete the row using interop. Here's a link to get you started on excel interop: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C